# Discord.py: 429 rate limit. What does "not making requests on exhausted buckets until after they have reset" exactly mean?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Recently, my bot was temporarily banned for a 429 rate limit code. And from what I can understand that means that it is making too many requests. But in the [discord developer portal rate limit](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits) site, it said that to avoid 429 responses, I should "avoid by inspecting the rate limit headers documented above and **by not making requests on exhausted buckets until after they have reset**"

I do not understand what the bolded text means. I can obviously tell it means that I have to wait until an exhausted bucket resets before using it again but what is a bucket, how does a bucket get exhausted, how am I/how is it getting exhausted and when/how does it reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the page you linked,

> "Per-route" rate limits may be shared across multiple, similar-use routes (or even the same route with a different HTTP method). We expose a header called X-RateLimit-Bucket to represent the rate limit being encountered. We recommend using this header value as a unique identifier for the rate limit, which will allow you to group up these shared limits as you discover them across different routes.

... Or in other words, the HTTP response will contain a header called `X-RateLimit-Bucket`, which will contain an identifying string for the API route you are using. That means that if you were to send thousands of requests to 1 specific API endpoint, Discord will presumably return the same `X-RateLimit-Bucket` ID in each response.

Along with the `X-RateLimit-Bucket` header, a few more headers are sent:

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1470173023
X-RateLimit-Bucket: abcd1234
X-RateLimit-Reset-After: 64.5
```

The documentation for all these headers are listed in the same page, although the one you should be looking out for here is `X-RateLimit-Reset-After` and `X-RateLimit-Remaining`. The 'Remaining' header states how many more requests can you make to this endpoint before you are blocked (429 HTTP error). The 'Reset-After' header states how long you must wait (in seconds) until the current bucket ID will reset, and you will be able to send requests again to this bucket.

In other words, a bucket gets exhausted by you sending requests to it, and it is fully exhausted once the `X-RateLimit-Remaining` HTTP response header is equal to 0. It automatically resets, and does so after the `X-RateLimit-Reset-After` HTTP response header is equal to 0 (the seconds you have to wait until you can send requests to that bucket ID is 0).

---

Update:

As these bits of information are returned as headers, you just have to print the `response.headers` value to the screen. That will give you all the returned headers. For example, if you want the remaining requests, then you'd execute `print(response.headers["X-RateLimit-Remaining"])` (the headers are returned as a dictionary).

However if you are indirectly interacting with the API (using the `discord.py` module), I'm not sure that this is possible without some edits to the module. After scouring the internet, I haven't managed to find anything that even gets close to exposing the underlying Session object for the module. However, while reading through the [request method](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/263f45d05bc512f7529d15001aad495e1327f67a/discord/http.py#L153) I found [this line](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/263f45d05bc512f7529d15001aad495e1327f67a/discord/http.py#L217), which hints that the module detects the Rate limiting by itself and stops you from sending any requests (if the bucket is exhausted).

Comment: Had to re-type this comment because I forget to @ you, lol. Is there a way I can print these values to the console for example? `print(bucket_limit_remaining)`

Comment: @goose.mp4 I updated the answer to include more information about detection of these values, however if you want to ask more questions I think you will need to make a new thread for it, as they are extending beyond the bound of the question (or make an edit to the question, but make sure it is still relevant to the original question). If I helped you / my answer is correct, it would be kind if you could checkmark it (the button on the left of my answer)  :)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful answer and thoroughly answered my question. I didn't want to mark the question as an answer yet because I just had the one comment. But yes, I will mark it as an answer and I will be making another thread if I need anymore help.