# I got this error : "The HTTP client has exhausted a per-route ratelimit. Locking route for 0.999 seconds" when using discord interactions library

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord-interactions

I'm trying to use the Discord Interactions library.
I writed this code in python :

```
import interactions

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
BOT_KEY = os.getenv("BOT_KEY")
if BOT_KEY is None:
    raise ValueError("BOT_KEY not found")


class MainClient:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        intents = interactions.Intents.ALL
        self.Client = interactions.Client(BOT_KEY, intents=intents)

    def start(self):
        self.Client.start()


interactions_client = MainClient()


@interactions_client.Client.event(name="on_ready")
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot command ready")


@interactions_client.Client.command(name="test", description="Do nothing, just a test")
async def test(context: interactions.CommandContext):
    pass


interactions_client.start()
```

I got this warning when i lauch the bot:
"The HTTP client has exhausted a per-route ratelimit. Locking route for 0.999 seconds."
The bot is runnig and is functionnal but i am concerned about this warning, I would like to understand it, fix the issue, and use this library correctly, but I don't see what I did wrong in my code. And I cannot find any helpful information that shows me my error. Furthermore, this library is not known to ChatGPT :(

I was looking [Discord.py: 429 rate limit. What does "not making requests on exhausted buckets until after they have reset" exactly mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268074/discord-py-429-rate-limit-what-does-not-making-requests-on-exhausted-buckets).

But i didnt understand whats the problems in my code.
I dont see where i do too many request.

I hope someone explains my error to me and how to correct it